# How to filter xml data type column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I have a table with two xml columns and the data inside the table is large. I would like to filter on the column which is of xml type to check if it contains a ID.

My sample xml column `IncomingXML` and value looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sws="abc">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <To xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">abc</To>
        <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">student</Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sws:ProvisionStudent>
          <sws:provisionStudentInput>
            <sws:Operation>U</sws:Operation>
            <sws:ADAccount>SU123456789</sws:ADAccount>
            <sws:ADPassword>abcde</sws:ADPassword>
            <sws:Prefix />
            <sws:FirstName>ancd</sws:FirstName>
            <sws:LastName>xyz</sws:LastName>
            <sws:MiddleName />
            <sws:Suffix />
            <sws:Email>abc@yahoo.com</sws:Email>
            <sws:EmplId>123456789</sws:EmplId>
            <sws:CampusCode />
            <sws:CompletionYear>0</sws:CompletionYear>
            <sws:CurrentCumulativeGpa>0</sws:CurrentCumulativeGpa>
            <sws:GraduationGpa />
            <sws:GraduationProgramCode />
            <sws:ProgramCode />
            <sws:UserType />
          </sws:provisionStudentInput>
        </sws:ProvisionStudent>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help me with a query like

```
select * 
from table 
where IncomingXML like '%SU123456789%'
```

I tried the following but did not have any luck.

```
select * 
from table 
where cast(IncomingXML as nvarchar(max)) like '%SU123456789%'
```

Comment: While the `CAST` approach is crude compared to formulating an XQuery, it [does in fact work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6898abc2f60efe3dec686de3f96334fe), so if you get no results it strongly suggests the XML is not what you think it is.

Comment: it may work, but with the data I have in that table, it is taking long time to give the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XQuery for this

```sql
DECLARE @toSearch nvarchar(100) = 'SU123456789';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv,
    DEFAULT 'abc'
)
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.IncomingXML.exist('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ProvisionStudent/provisionStudentInput/ADAccount[text() = sql:variable("@toSearch")]') = 1;
```

To search in any node, at the cost of efficiency

```sql
DECLARE @toSearch nvarchar(100) = 'SU123456789';

SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.IncomingXML.exist('//*[text() = sql:variable("@toSearch")]') = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c8b86716edfe4f14cb5ca9923ac028c)

You can obviously also embed a literal instead of a variable in the XQuery.